# IOS 10 Xcode 8 NSString From NSDictionary returns nil

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, plist, ios10

This feels like a bug, this code worked perfect before iOS 10.
Has anyone noticed anything similar?
heres the code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:className ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSDictionary *animationSettings = plistDictionary[animationName];
float delayPerUnit = [animationSettings[@"delay"] floatValue];

NSString *animationFrames = animationSettings[@"animationFrames"];
// NSString is empty here

NSArray *animationFrameNumbers = [animationFrames componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
// NSArray is empty because NSString is empty.
```

I found a workaround

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:className ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSDictionary *animationSettings = plistDictionary[animationName];
float delayPerUnit = [animationSettings[@"delay"] floatValue];

NSString *animationFrames = animationSettings[@"animationFrames"];

// If I add 1 to animationFrames, then everything works fine.

 if (!animationFrames) {
 animationFrames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
 }

NSArray *animationFrameNumbers = [animationFrames componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Not Sure if this is a bug, or I'm doing something wrong. thanX for the help!!! :D

Comment: Use the debugger and see what `plistDictionary` contains.

Comment: Check for what plistDictionary contains. Also check the key that you are using to get the animationSettings